# Modifying a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that calculates the balance available based on ledger entries as shown below. I would like to edit and add an additional parameter; The original SP only performs this query:

```
SELECT SUM([amount value]) as [Bal available]  
FROM  [xxxxxxxxxxxx $Ledger Entries] 
WHERE [Entry No_] ='number_here'
```

But I want it to achieve:

```
SELECT SUM([amount value]) as [Bal available]  
FROM  [xxxxxxxxxxxx $Ledger Entries] 
WHERE [Transaction Type] ='TYPE1' and [Entry No_] ='number_here'`
```

Any suggestions?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[loadbal] 
    (
    @Company_Name varchar(100),
    @EntNo varchar(100)
    )
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(4000)

SET @TableName='['+@Company_Name+' $Ledger Entries]'

SELECT @SQL = ' SELECT SUM([amount value]) as [Bal available]  
                FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE [Entry No_] ='+@EntNo

EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

Comment: Bit confused as it would appear you have answered your own question?

Comment: This code appears to be susceptible to SQL injection. Suppose a malicious entity engineers a situation where the proc is called with a company name of `'Blah]; DROP TABLE [Users]; --'`

Comment: i wanted to achieve it in a stored procedure. The solution below worked, i was using 'TYPE1' rather than ''TYPE1''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change Your `Select` Statement as follow :

```
SELECT @SQL = ' SELECT SUM([amount value]) as [Bal available]  FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE [Transaction Type] = ''TYPE1'' AND [Entry No_] ='+@EntNo
```

SQL `Query` will look like as :

```
 SELECT SUM([amount value]) as [Bal available]  FROM [ $Ledger Entries] WHERE [Transaction Type] = 'TYPE1' AND [Entry No_] = <whatever u have passed here>
```